# returning empty set even if sql query is correct

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `states`. The data is like this:

```
+----------------------+--------------------+
| value                | name               |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| andaman-nicobar-map  | Andaman-Nicobar    |
| andhra-pradesh-map   | Andhra-Pradesh     |
| arunachal-map        | Arunachal          |
| assam-map            | Assam              |
| bihar-map            | Bihar              |
| chandigarh-map       | Chandigarh         |
| chattisgarh-map      | Chattisgarh        |
| daman-map            | Daman              |
+----------------------+--------------------+

SELECT * FROM `states` WHERE `name`='Bihar';
```

but this query is returning an empty result set.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem sharing an **sql fiddle**?

Comment: What is the type of `name`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have whitespace in the `name` column, which is why the exact comparison is failing.  Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM states
WHERE TRIM(name) = 'Bihar'
```

or this:

```
SELECT *
FROM states
WHERE name LIKE '%Bihar%'
```

If either of these work, then you'll know that you have extra characters in the `name` column.

Comment: Thanks Tim But No Luck

Comment: Then please share your data as it is in your table @SwarnimGupta

Comment: above is the all data